# Parse Push Notifications Received only in first installation and first opening of app

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have an `android` application and i am using `parse.com` to send notification onto my device. `GCM` is working fine for me but when I am trying to send the notification through `Parse`'s  own backend I get the notification in first installation and in first opening of app. But when I don't get any notification after closing the app or opening it again.Data Browser on `Parse.com` is displaying the `pushes` as sent. I think Parse receiver is going to sleep. I have done the same as told in quick start on the `Parse.com` and using teh latest `Parse sdk` version. Please if anyone can help. 
here is my intialization code:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Initialize Crash Reporting.
        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        // Add your initialization code here
         Parse.initialize(this, "IqApr1J4HMGwfa...........", "Imm42YnYURaH........"); 
         ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

      }
    }
```

And here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Package_Name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="Package_Name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ParseStarterProjectActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: the code of your parse initialization and subscribing would be helpfull

Comment: Added the code please review it.

Comment: Why is the GcmBroadcastReceiver missing in your Manifest? When I used Parse It didn't work without it.

Comment: I want to test if the Parse Push works, that's why I removed the `GcmBroadcastReceiver` . If i add it Parse prefers `gcm` over its own push notifications. Without it the parse is working but only on the first opening of app after installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you subscribe to the parse push service somewhere in your app like this:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(/*any channel or just ""*/, new SaveCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is it necessary to subscribe? I will check it out. And where do I put it, in my application class or the activity class ?

Comment: i always put it in my activity. it doesnt matter, if you call the subscribe method more often. it just refreshes the date of subscription and so you can verify, if the user is active or not.

Comment: Added this method to my Activity class. It just let my App installation subscribe to [""] channel, but doesn't solve my original problem. I still don't get any notifications after i close and open the my app the second time. I only receive notification on the first time i open the app.

Comment: I solved it. The problem was in my android phone. It was Xiaomi. tested the same apk on samsung and it worked. Thanks for all of your replies. :)